# Create rails form that redirects to show route of another resource by select id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a dropdown containing states and populates via the db. On submit, I want the app to direct to the show route for states. Alas, I get an error.

The routes.rb file contains:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'app/index'

  resources :states
  root 'beerfinder#index'
end
```

The states controller contains:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @state = State.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

The app controller

```
class AppController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @states = State.all
  end
end
```

My form for the index.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for :states, :url => states_path(@state) do |f| %> 
    <%=select_tag 'state', options_from_collection_for_select(@states, 'id', 'full_name')%>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>            
<% end %>
```

The State table contains id and full_name fields. Currently, the form looks for the create route. How do I make this route to the state view without using js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal for `states_path` to route to the *index* action on the controller for a 'get' request. You'd use the `state_path` route helper to get to the `show` action. But the `state_path` route helper requires the id of the resource to show. You don't know that at the form level because there are many options in the select tag, each with a different id.

The normal way to access the show action from a `resources :states` route is to have the id in the URL path, eg. `/states/101`.

Using a `<form>` and a `<select>` will generate a URL parameter in the request. You require something like `/states/show?id=101`.

The following works, but I'm not sure it's the most Rails-y way of doing it:

Make a new '/states/show' alternate route in routes.rb (with no :id in the URL) *before* the `resources :states` route:

```
get 'states/show', to: 'places#show'
resources :states
```

Then your form_for becomes a form_tag (because you are not working with a single resource):

```
form_tag :url => states_show_path, :method => :get
```

And your `select_tag` changes so it submits an 'id' URL param:

```
select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@states, 'id', 'full_name')
```

It would be simpler with JavaScript (no messing around with customized routes), but that's the best non-JS solution I can think of.

Comment: So, the get request did try and point it at the index action, so it wasn't quite there. I tried to change it to 'state_path' and it it now errors when trying to render the form


No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"states", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into it and if there isn't any normal rails magic for this, I think I might just go the js route and agree with your estimation that it is simpler to do that.